# Overflow Hidden Hides Postion Absolute Block. If Position Absolute block is out of the parent block than it is disappered

Tags: html, css

This is my style.

```
<style>
.wrapper { margin:0px auto; height:600px; width:600px; position:relative; background:#F2F7FF; padding:20px; overflow:hidden }
.pos-rel { width:90%; background:#FFF; height:400px; position:relative; padding:5%; }
.pos-abs { position:absolute; height:100px; width:200px; position:absolute; background:#89BCFF; border:1px solid #517099; right:-110px; }
</style>
```

This is my HTML :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    Wrapper
    <div class="pos-rel">
        Position relative Parent block
        <div class="pos-abs">
            Position Absoulute child block
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/Ltfx7/8/)

Problem is :
The block having position absolute is visible only half. Half block is hidden due to wrapper.

Before you give any solution, i must state that i have to used Overflow:hidden in the parent block.

Comment: why do you need to use overflow:hidden for the wrapper? Maybe you could avoid it, and probably this should be the true question

Comment: If you must have overflow:hidden in the wrapper, there is no way to make the absolute div visible outside the wrapper using just css. You'll need here some js code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can avoid parent's `overflow:hidden`, if you remove `position:relative` from `.wrapper`. [Here is working example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/zwnh9pl4)

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me what you want to create
like if you are using overflow: hidden then it will not come.
or else you have to reduce right minus margin from right.
can you make it more clear like why you want this..